# Find highest points of two students in a section

Tags: php, mysql

my table

[image]

Here I would like to display

Name of 2 students who got Highest point in each section (Sum of C1points to C3Points). Also display their each competitions and points. Duplicate marks also need to be displayed.

Kindly give query for just one section.

So final output looks

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: I am not sure about the query..

Comment: well lets see your query

Comment: i guess i should just post my questions as an anonymous user and not put any effort in That way i can get my work done without lifting a finger and still get points for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you results for a single section:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  SUM(C1Points) AS TotalC1,
  SUM(C2Points) AS TotalC2,
  SUM(C3Points) AS TotalC3,
  SUM(C1Points + C2Points + C3Points) AS TotalAll
FROM myTable
WHERE Section = 'Section1'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY TotalAll DESC
LIMIT 2
```

To read all sections at once with MySQL is complicated. It's better to read everything and order it correctly, then use PHP to get the first two rows for each section:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Section,
  SUM(C1Points) AS TotalC1,
  SUM(C2Points) AS TotalC2,
  SUM(C3Points) AS TotalC3,
  SUM(C1Points + C2Points + C3Points) AS TotalAll
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Name, Section
ORDER BY Section, TotalAll DESC
```

You'll get a result set like this:

```
Section 1 first place name and scores
Section 1 second place name and scores
Section 1 third place name and scores
. . .
Section 1 last place name and scores
Section 2 first place name and scores
Section 2 second place name and scores
and so on...
```

With the list ordered like this, grabbing the top two rows for each section would be child's play in PHP.

Comment: I would be thankful if you can identify any inefficiencies in my query, I can see a lot of scope but am not able to pinpoint any

Comment: No glaring inefficiencies. This type of thing is complicated in MySQL, so efficiency takes a hit anyway. One recommendation: format your queries better. You've got three levels of subquery with no indenting and no separation of `SELECT` from `WHERE` from `GROUP BY`. I had to copy and indent before I could understand it. I'd recommend finding a formatting/indenting scheme that you're comfortable with and applying it consistently; you'll be glad you did. Still, excellent job; I'll vote it up :)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, I have formatted the query now

Comment: Thanks Ed Gibbs for your effort. you guys are amazing. Great work..Love you.

Comment: @EdGibbs - Nice explanation of aggregate functions for a new user!

Answer (score 2):

This solution will give you output for all the sections at once, you just need to modify the structure of the table and add total

So imagining you have this

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (NAME VARCHAR(10), SECTION VARCHAR(20), 
                  C1 INTEGER, C2 INTEGER, C3 INTEGER);

INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ('S1','Section1',5,0,3),
                ('S2','Section2',0,0,5),
                ('S3','Section3',5,5,5),
                ('S4','Section3',3,3,0),
                ('S5','Section1',5,0,3),
                ('S6','Section2',0,1,0),
                ('S7','Section3',0,0,0),
                ('S8','Section3',5,0,5),
                ('S9','Section1',5,0,3),
                ('S10','Section2',0,3,0),
                ('S11','Section1',3,0,0),
                ('S12','Section3',5,5,5),
                ('S13','Section1',0,1,1),
                ('S14','Section2',3,5,0),
                ('S15','Section3',1,0,0);
```

Now you need to add

```
ALTER TABLE STUDENT ADD COLUMN TOTAL INTEGER;
```

and Update the values

```
UPDATE STUDENT SET TOTAL = C1+C2+C3;
```

Then you can run this query

```
   SELECT SECTION,
       NAME,
       C1,
       C2,
       C3,
       TOTAL
FROM STUDENT
WHERE CONCAT(SECTION,TOTAL) IN
    (SELECT IDENTIFIER
     FROM
       (SELECT CONCAT(SECTION,MAX(TOTAL)) AS IDENTIFIER,
               SECTION,
               MAX(TOTAL) AS MARKS
        FROM STUDENT
        GROUP BY SECTION
        UNION SELECT CONCAT(SECTION,MAX(TOTAL)) AS IDENTIFIER,
                     SECTION,
                     MAX(TOTAL) AS MAKRS
        FROM STUDENT AS A
        WHERE TOTAL <
            (SELECT MAX(TOTAL)
             FROM STUDENT
             WHERE SECTION = A.SECTION)
        GROUP BY SECTION) AS RESULT)
ORDER BY SECTION,
         TOTAL DESC
```

You can see the results

[image]

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f18e1/24/0

Hope this helps, no PHP at all needed, though it may be actually more efficient to do part of this in PHP or another server side script

Comment: Actually the results you have in the question are wrong as per the data you have :) in that s8's total marks is only 10 - Just for fun

Comment: in case if you cannot alter the original table structure you can create a view and do this on the view

Comment: Or, instead of using `TOTAL` you can substitute `C1+C2+C3`. @user2594154: this query will do what you're asking for. It's complicated because your requirement is complicated - at least in MySQL which doesn't have an analytic RANK function like Oracle or SQL Server. skv has spent a lot of time on it, so if it works for you please vote it up and accept it.

Comment: I am very thankful to you SKV. You have a worked a lot for me. Thank you so much from bottom of my heart. Great.. Great my friend.

Comment: Thank you, I am happy that I am able to help